# Error 404 on /bin browsing

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, http-status-code-404, bin-folder

I run IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I'm getting a `404: file not found` error when I browse the "/bin" folder. I understand that this is a security policy by Microsoft.

I tried doing what is written in [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/54e9382b-743d-495e-a324-b8b57a5214ee.mspx?mfr=true) but it didn't solve the issue. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Should be noted that I have no security issues. I run the IIS for direcotry browsing in a private network. Eventually I need to perform crawling and indexing on it. The problem is that pages under "/bin" and '/AppConfig" are not being crawled because of the 404 error.

I just need a solution for this issue. Again, no security issues are relevant here.

Comment: IIS 6 on Windows 2008 R2 is not possible. W2008 R2 is shipped with IIS 7.5. In all cases, browsing to bin is unsafe. Why would you do that ?

Comment: Make an aspx page that read and show this bin with secure and only on logged in users...

Comment: Steve, you're right, my mistake.

Comment: @user1251654: so the link you provided is no more valid as it points to W2K3 kb

Comment: Aristos, I didnt understand your solution. can't I change some configuration to allow directory browsing to this folders?

Comment: Steve, Yes I know. I didnt find any other solution for iis 7.5 so I tried what is written in the link.

Comment: See an example for what I mean: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301328/ASP-NETUser-Control-File-Browser

Comment: Bin is better to stay as it is to avoid get any virus or intruder.

Comment: @user1251654: please explain your requirement. We may find a solution to allow browsing BIN, but it's not a good practice. There is maybe other way to reach your goal.

Comment: Ok, I edited my quesion with clarification - no security issuses. I only need a solution that will alove browsing on all the blocked directories.

Comment: @user1251654: this is not a requirement. What you are asking here is how to solve a technical problem, not what is your real goal (the business requirement probably). What I'm asking is you describe your goal. Why would you have to browse the bin directory?

Comment: As I said - I crawl and index the filesystem. I need to do this via http and not via filesystem protocol becuase of other reasons. consider it as a base assumption. assume the only access I have to a filesystem which I need to crawl and index is via this directory browsing . /bin is one of the folders in the filesystem and thus I need to access it and index it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bin folder is not intended as a place where a developer should put web pages.

In IIS 7.5 you can configure

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
2. In the Connections   pane, go to the connection, site, application, or directory for
   which you want to modify your request filtering settings.
3. In the Home pane, double-click Request Filtering.
4. In the **Request Filtering pane**, click the Hidden Segments tab
5. Select the relative path that you want to show (BIN folder), and then  click Remove in the Actions pane.

The same can be done via web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="false">
           <remove segment="Bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Anyway, in orded to avoid problems on development server and on any deploy server, i think that **the easiest solution is to move that pages to another folder**.

---

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx):

```
ASP.NET recognizes certain folder names that you can use   
for specific types of content.  
The following table lists the reserved folder names and the type   
of files that the folders typically contain.

Note
The content of application folders, except for the App_Themes folder,
is not served in response to Web requests,
but it can be accessed from application code.
```

- `App_Browsers` Contains browser definitions (.browser files) that
  ASP.NET uses to identify individual browsers and determine their
  capabilities.
- `App_Code` Contains source
  code for shared classes and business objects
- `App_Data` Contains application data files
  including .mdf database files, XML files, and other data store files.
- `App_GlobalResources`
  Contains resources (.resx and .resources files) that are compiled
  into assemblies with global scope.
- `App_LocalResources` Contains resources (.resx and
  .resources files) that are associated with a specific page, user
  control, or master page in an application
- `App_Themes` Contains a collection
  of files (.skin and .css files, as well as image files and generic
  resources) that define the appearance of ASP.NET Web pages and
  controls.
- `App_WebReferences` Contains reference contract files (.wsdl files),
  schemas (.xsd files), and discovery document files (.disco and
  .discomap files) that let you create a Web reference for use in an
  application.
- `Bin`
  Contains compiled assemblies (.dll files) for controls, components,
  or other code that you want to reference in your application.

Comment: We are hosting WordPress sites on IIS and plugins and themes like to use a bin folder for images and other assets, which broke styling and logo. We removed bin from the list of folders for that specific site and it worked great. Windows 2012, IIS 8.

Comment: @ahwm yes, you can do it an it works.. but Bin folder isn't intended for this purpouse. That's why this folder is protected by default. Now some private content can be served to users.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of that. That's why I enabled the bin folder *for that website **only***. A lot of PHP-based applications tend to make use of the bin folder in this fashion, even though they're not really supposed to (on *nix servers it doesn't matter).

Comment: Also, I should point out that the web application in IIS is only hosting a WordPress site. There's no ASP.NET application or anything and no bin folder in the website root. It's nested in like `site.com/wp-content/themes/theme/bin/` and in this instance this solution should be perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

- Access \bin folder over network share, e.g. `\\myserver\mysite\bin`
- Write ashx handler or asmx web service which will scan \bin folder for you and return the result for you, e.g. `Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~\bin"))`

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to disable this security configuration in IIS?

Comment: @user1251654: I don't know such way, google gave nothing too, and honestly I doubt that this ways even exist.